# Using the word "impressive"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Basically a friend of mine is working with me right now and we're translating a few things.

In a tear-jerking scene where two sisters are reunited, my friend insisted on translating it to "an impressive reunion" whereas I was thinking of "heartwarming". My impression of impressive are mostly among the lines of "leaving a deep impression" or "awe-inspiring". Can it be used to describe tear-inducing matters? I've never touched upon that kind of usage before...

Answer (score 1):

Your friend should look it up. Using "impressive" here doesn't make a whole lot of sense:

> impressive: Making a strong positive impression; inspiring admiration or awe

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=impressive))

Depending on the broader context, a word like **"emotional"** could work to describe the reunion:

> emotional: making people have strong feelings
>
> *The funeral was a very emotional experience for all of us.*

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/emotional))

Answer (score 1):

Your impression of "impressive" is right. Impressive could be considered as long as it makes a good impression, but I would recommend using the following 2 adjectives.

Very broadly used adjective is "[***touching***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/touching)" which means:

> Arousing feelings of sympathy or gratitude: your loyalty is very
>   touching a ***touching*** reconciliation scene

Another possible candidate is [***moving***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moving):

> Producing strong emotion, ***especially sadness*** or sympathy: an
>   unforgettable and moving book

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

The following shows usage of 3 adjectives. "an impressive scene" has been losing popularity since the beginning of the 20th century.

[image]

[Ngram Viewer]

Comment: I was aware of touching and moving but since it was a happy reunion I wanted to emphasize that a bit. But thanks for the recommendations anyway.

Comment: @anonymous You specifically mentioned "tear-jerking" and that's why I suggested those words. Why not use "tear-jerking reunion scene"?